# Add last modified date to FAQ

Tags: feature-request, timestamps

I seem to have gotten some new privileges recently.  Being concerned that it might be a bug since I hadn't heard of any changes, I checked meta, the blog, and the FAQ for more information.  I noticed the FAQ now has additional privileges at the 15K and 20K levels.  To satisfy my curiosity over whether I'm simply clueless and these have been there for sometime or whether they were introduced overnight, it would be nice for the FAQ to be dated so we can see when the last change was made.  I realize that there is a revision number in the footer, but it's unclear if that applies to the FAQ itself or to the software; I'm assuming the latter.

Comment: Just to sate your own curiosity: that set of changes to the FAQ was made in-hand with the actual privilege changes. According to [the Recent Feature Changes log](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), that was on February 9th, 2011.

Comment: @Grace - I guess I've been busier at work than I thought. Thanks. Do you know if the nav bar notification for flagged items was introduced at the same time.  My cursory look didn't turn that up.

Comment: That I think was just introduced today, actually. But I'm not sure. I don't see such a thing myself on account of not being of high enough privilege level on any site.